# Refer to parent's class method without parent's class name

Tags: python, python-decorators, class-method

I hope you are doing great. This questions is really about getting rid of the reference to base class.

Basically I want to collect all methods of a child class methods at the class level instead of the instance level, using a parent classmethod. However, I was told that the base class name is really long.

The first piece works but is really annoying because of the long name. Even in the clean version I have to do A.eat everytime.

I promise people won't define another method "eat" in any child like B. Can I actually get rid of the base class reference so that I can use @eat?

```
class IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong(object):

  a = []

  @classmethod
  def eat(cls, func):
    cls.a.append(func)


class B(IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong):

  @IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong.eat
  def apple( self, x ):
    print x

  IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong.eat( lambda x: x+1 )

x = B()

IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong.a[0](x, 1)

print IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong.a[1](1)
```

Clean version:

```
class A(object):

  a = []

  @classmethod
  def eat(cls, func):
    cls.a.append(func)


class B(A):

  @A.eat
  def apple( self, x ):
    print x

  A.eat( lambda x: x+1 )

x = B()

A.a[0](x, 1)
print A.a[1](1)
```

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong` is really just an object. In python, most thingsa are an object, so we can assign just about anything to a variable, including a class.

What you could do here is something like the following

```
class IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong(object):

    a = []

    @classmethod
    def eat(cls, func):
        cls.a.append(func)

A = IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong


class B(A):

    @A.eat
    def apple( self, x ):
        print x

    A.eat( lambda x: x+1 )

x = B()

IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong.a[0](x, 1)        
A.a[0](x, 1)

print IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong.a[1](1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no perfect solution for what you want to do, but there are a few different approaches that might be good enough.

To start with the simplest, you could give your long class a shorter name before using class method in the child classes:

```
class IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong(object):
    ...

A = IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong

# later code can use A.whatever()
```

Another option would be to move the decorator out of the class with the long name, so that your later code would refer to it directly as a global, rather than a class method. This would require it to be slightly redesigned (which might break things if you ever intend for there to be multiple different `a` lists that are accessed through the same decorator called via different classes):

```
class IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong(object):
    a = []

def eat(func):
    IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong.a.append(func) # only need to use the name once
    return func  # I suspect you want this too (a decorator should return a callable)

# later code can use @eat as a decorator, without referring to the long class name
```

A hybrid of those two approaches might be to leave the existing class method definition intact, but to create another global name for the bound method that's easier to access:

```
eat = IDontWantToDoThisButNameHasToBeThisLong.eat
```

A final possible approach would be to use fancier programming with metaclasses, or (if you're using Python 3.6) `__init_subclass__` or similar, to achieve the goal you have in mind without needing to use a class method as a decorator. I'm not going to include code for that, since the best way to do this probably depends on more details of your design than what you've show in your example.